# retrofit2 with coroutine or not, what's the difference?

Tags: android

when I use retrofit2 with no coroutine, the result is null. but when using that with coroutine, the result is right. I think it's the problem of syncronization. but I found something strange
using mutablelivedata, the result is right.

*retrofit2 with coroutine*

```
    override suspend fun getRetrofit(id : Int): DetailEntity {

        withContext(ioDispatcher){
            val request = taskNetworkSource.searchItem(id)
            val response = request.await()

            if(response.body !=null){
                Log.d("TAG",""+response.toString())
                data = response
            }


        }
        return data
    }
```

*good result*

```
D/TAG: DetailEntity(body=DetatilItem(oily_score=6, full_size_image=url, price=54840, sensitive_score=76, description=description, id=5, dry_score=79, title=title), statusCode=200)
```

*retrofit2 with no coroutine*

```
       override suspend fun getRetrofit(id : Int): DetailEntity {

        taskNetworkSource.searchItem(id).enqueue(object: Callback<DetailEntity> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DetailEntity>, t: Throwable) {

            }
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<DetailEntity>, response: Response<DetailEntity>){
                if(response.body()!=null) {
                    Log.d("TAG",response.toString())
                    data = response.body()!!

                }

            }
        })

        return data
    }
```

*bad result*

```
D/TAG: Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://6uqljnm1pb.execute-api.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/products/5}
```

*strange result with mutablelivedata(another project code)*

```
    lateinit var dataSet : DetailModel             
    var data = MutableLiveData<DetailModel>()       

    fun getDetailRetrofit(id:Int) : MutableLiveData<DetailModel>{          
        Retrofit2Service.getService().requestIndexItem(id).enqueue(object:
            Callback<DetailResponse> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DetailResponse>, t: Throwable) {    

            }
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<DetailResponse>, response: Response<DetailResponse>) {   
                if(response.body()!=null) {
                    var res = response.body()!!.body
                    dataSet = DetailModel( res.get(0).discount_cost,
                        res.get(0).cost,
                        res.get(0).seller,
                        res.get(0).description+"\n\n\n",
                        res.get(0).discount_rate,
                        res.get(0).id,
                        res.get(0).thumbnail_720,
                        res.get(0).thumbnail_list_320,
                        res.get(0).title
                    )
                    data.value = dataSet
                }
            }
        })
        return data
    }
```

and this another project code result is right. comparing this code to retrofit2 with no coroutine code, the difference is only mutablelivedata or not. do I have to use asyncronouse library or livedata?

added

```
data class DetailEntity(val body: DetatilItem,
                        val statusCode: Int = 0)

data class DetatilItem(val oily_score: Int = 0,
                       val full_size_image: String = "",
                       val price: String = "",
                       val sensitive_score: Int = 0,
                       val description: String = "",
                       val id: Int = 0,
                       val dry_score: Int = 0,
                       val title: String = "")
```

Comment: `with no coroutine` response, it seems to be no problem. Why is it problem?

Comment: I thought  like you, but as u see the log say me there is different result. so I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

*retrofit with no coroutine it seem to be no problem.*

But, `respnose` at your code written to log are the completely different object.

with coroutine, `response` is `DetailEntity`

with no coroutine, `response` is `Response<DetailEntity>`

### if you want same log print, try as below

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<DetailEntity>, response: Response<DetailEntity>){
    if(response.body()!=null) {
        Log.d("TAG",response.body()!!.toString())
        data = response.body()!!
    }
}
```

## Reference

[Retrofit - Response<T>](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html)

Comment: thank you, but when I log this two method with coroutine or not in view model, the result with no coroutine show. "D/TAG ViewModel: DetailEntity(body=DetatilItem(oily_score=0, full_size_image=, price=, sensitive_score=0, description=, id=0, dry_score=0, title=), statusCode=0)". but with coroutine show "D/TAG ViewModel: DetailEntity(body=DetatilItem(oily_score=6, full_size_image=url, price=54840, sensitive_score=76, description=description), statusCode=200)"

Comment: @jakchang umm... that looks like an issue related to serialization. Can you attach more information to your question? (response raw string `response.body().string()` and `DetailEntity` class.)

Comment: response.body.toString() in viewmodel . with corutine.
"D/TAG ViewModel: DetailEntity(body=DetatilItem(oily_score=6, full_size_image=url, price=54840, sensitive_score=76, description=description), statusCode=200)"   with no coroutine. "D/TAG ViewModel: DetailEntity(body=DetatilItem(oily_score=0, full_size_image=, price=, sensitive_score=0, description=, id=0, dry_score=0, title=), statusCode=0)".  And I added DetailEntity class

Comment: @jakchang `response.body.toString()` is different from `response.body().string()`.